# Ruby: HTTParty: can't format XML POST data correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, http-post, httparty

NOTE: "object" is a placeholder work, as I don't think I should be saying what the controller does specifically.

so, I have multiple ways of calling my apps API, the following works in the command line:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' -d '<object><name>Test API object</name><password>password</password><description>This is a test object</description></object>' "http://acme.example.dev/objects.xml?api_key=1234"
```

the above command generates the following request in the devlog:

```
Processing ObjectsController#create to xml (for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-07-07 09:17:51) [POST]
  Parameters: {"format"=>"xml", "action"=>"create", "api_key"=>"1234", "controller"=>"objects", 
  "object"=>{"name"=>"Test API object", "description"=>"This is a test object", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
```

Now, I'm trying to write tests for the actions using the API, to make sure the API works, as well as the controllers.
Here is my current (broken) httparty command:

```
  response = post("create", :api_key => SharedTest.user_api_key, :xml => data, :format => "xml")
```

this command generates the following request in the testlog:

```
Processing ObjectsController#create to xml (for 0.0.0.0 at 2011-07-07 09:37:35) [POST]
  Parameters: {
        "xml"=>"<object><name><![CDATA[first post]]></name>
                    <description><![CDATA[Things are not as they used to be]]></description>
                    <password><![CDATA[WHEE]]></password>
                </object>", 
                "format"=>"xml", 
                "api_key"=>"the_hatter_wants_to_have_tea1", 
                "action"=>"create", 
                "controller"=>"objects
```

So, as you can see, the command line command actually generates the object hash from the xml, whereas the httparty command ends up staying in xml, which causes problems for the create method, as it needs a hash.

Any ideas / proper documentation?
Current documentation says that post takes an url, and "options" and then never says what options are available

---

****EDIT**:
as per @Casper's suggestion, my method now looks like this:

```
def post_through_api_to_url(url, data, api_key = SharedTest.user_api_key)

  response = post("create", {
    :query => {
      :api_key => api_key
    },
    :headers => {
      "Content-Type" => "application/xml"
    },
    :body => data
  })
  ap @request.env["REQUEST_URI"]
  assert_response :success

  return response
end
```

unfortunately, the assert_response fails, because the authentication via the api key fails. 
looking at the very of of the request_uri, the api_key isn't being set properly... it shows:

```
api_key%5D=the_hatter_wants_to_have_tea1"
```

but it should just be equals, without the %5D (right square bracket)

Comment: Strange..are you able to see what the posted URL looks like? When I do the above and look at the generated HTTP request I get `POST /create?api_key=blahblah HTTP/1.1`, which is valid HTTP and should decode the api_key correctly..where does the right square bracket suddenly come from?

Comment: Just the httparty uri? yeah, that's how I saw the %5D=

Comment: I tihnk the square bracket comes from nested attirbutes. Cause when I do :search => {:name_like => "blah"} the {} get turned into [] which get turned into %5B and %5D

Comment: Well. All I can say it all smells a bit fishy. If I was you I would seriously strip down the application to bare bones, or possibly just build a minimal test application until you know how each part works. Right now you have too many moving parts in there..start with just a simple one ruby file where you do a post, and see if you can get that to work. Just the simplest thing..you have something seriously wonky with your app right now I think..strip off all the junk and then figure out what is breaking what. Eventually you'll figure it out..:)

Comment: Just to give you an idea what I mean by stripping everything out. Here's how I test this thing: http://i.imgur.com/2Bepy.png

Comment: I found the problem, and why I'm getting brackets.... it's because I'm telling things to go inside the query hash.... that's wrong. I've been printing the URL every time I change something....   post "create", :query => {:api_key => api_key}
 gives the following object?query%5Bapi_key%5D=the_hatter_wants_to_have_tea1"

Answer (score 1):

I think this is how you're supposed to use it:

```
options = {
  :query => {
    :api_key => 1234
  },

  :headers => {
    "Content-Type" => "application/xml"
  },

  :body => "<xmlcode>goes here</xmlcode>"
}

post("/create", options)
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me for being basic about it but if you only want to send one variable as a parameter, why don't you do as Casper suggests, but just do:

```
post("/create?api_key=1234", options)
```

Or rather than testing HTTParty's peculiarities in accessing your API, perhaps write your tests using [Rack::Test](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rack-test/0.6.0/frames)? Very rough example...

```
require "rack/test"
require "nokogiri"

class ObjectsTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  def app
    MyApp.new
  end

  def create_an_object(o)
    authorize "x", "1234" # or however you want to authenticate using query params
    header 'Accept', 'text/xml'
    header 'Content-Type', 'text/xml'
    body o.to_xml
    post "/create"

    xml = Nokogiri::XML(last_response.body)
    assert something_logic_about(xml)
  end

end
```